# Detect Youtube iFrame state changes (play/end/etc...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, iframe, youtube

Everything is in the title, I "just" would like to detect when my YouTube iFrame state is changing.

I'm using the API to search and display a set of 10 videos (*with `youtube.search.list`*), so I'm getting their `VideoID` then I use it to display videos in iFrame (*for each videos*). So I'm not using the API to set the player (*I tried but I didn't success*). Here is my code (*only the JS and `item.html`*) :

```js
function tplawesome(e,t){res=e;for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){res=res.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g,function(e,r){return t[n][r]})}return res}

$(function() {
    $("div[class^='play_it']").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       // prepare the request
       var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: "snippet",
            type: "video",
            q: encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('id')).replace(/%20/g, "+"),
            maxResults: 10,
            order: "relevance",
            videoSyndicated: "true",
            videoCategoryId: 10
       }); 
       // execute the request
       request.execute(function(response) {
          var results = response.result;
          var i = 0;
          var auto = "1";
          $(".videoss").html("");
          $.each(results.items, function(index, item) {
            $.get("tpl/item.html", function(data) {
             if (i != 0) {
              auto = "0";
             }
                $(".videoss").append(tplawesome(data, [{"title":item.snippet.title, "videoid":item.id.videoId, "auto":auto}]));
                i = i + 1;
            });
          });
       });
    });
});

function init() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("MY_API_KEY");
    gapi.client.load("youtube", "v3", function() {
        // yt api is ready
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
 <iframe class="video w100" width="364" height="205" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{{videoid}}?autoplay={{auto}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 <div class="player_title">{{title}}</div>
 <div class="player_divider"></div>
</div>
```

So it's now working, but I'm not very "API-youtube-&-JS_friendly" so I don't know how to launch the player with the API (*I tried but no success, only the first video is loading*) to make an `OnStateChange` function and make an autoplay of all the videos I get as a playlist (*and I didn't find a way to make it without the API*), so I need your help please.

> I'm using SO for a while but it's my first post and I don't speak english very well so don't be to sharp with me if I'm not acting nicely on this first post :)